# How to limit the number of times a google maps marker bounces?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using animation in google maps to cause a marker to bounce.

How can I change the following code to make it bounce only twice?

```
markersArray[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
```

EDIT:
Here's how I did it but as Michal said - it's a crude solution:

```
marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
setTimeout("marker.setAnimation(null)", 1520);
```

Comment: I'll go out on a limb here and say "you can't" — at least not using `setAnimation()`. The docs state `The following Animation values are currently supported` and the two possible values are constants. If you need more control, you'll probably have to roll your own animation solution, since this should really be an edge case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you cannot control the animation via the API.

A crude way of stopping the animation would be to time exactly how long two bounces last, setTimeout to that value and cancel the animation  with marker.setAnimation(null);

Comment: Michal, thanks. This is exactly what I did. The problem with this way is that each machine may time it a bit differently which will cause the animation to not end smoothly. But I guess it will have to do for now. I'll accept your answer and add my code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I took that "crude way of stopping the animation" and refined it a little in my answer on this [other (dup) SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339200/bounce-a-pin-in-google-maps-once).