# Google Places - Markers drop on to the map on scroll/zoom

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, google-places

I'm having an issue with Google maps Places. The places drop on the map each time I drag or zoom out on the map. Please see this here: http://www.jupixcreative.com/dev/places/search_results_map.php

Obviously I only want the places to drop when you load the map, and not every time you move or zoom the map.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Set a timeout for your markers in a for loop.

To set a timeout for one, just do the following

```
  marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  setTimeout(function(){ marker.setAnimation(null); }, 750);  //time it takes for one bounce
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7832086/1675954)

just add a loop and you should be sorted.

Comment: Hi Rachel,

Thanks for your help, the for loop did the job nicely.

Comment: @aboother please hover beside the answer and click the tick sign - it's worth 15 points to me! :)